# Add headers to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, header, navigation, drawer

I just followed this tutorial http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/ and I made an application that uses a Navigation Drawer. If you take a look at that link, you'll see that there are 2 parts: one in which he makes the app and one in which he is customizing it ( he adds a spinner and some headers). I want to add only the headers but I just can't figure out how.
I also checked the Google for some answers but didn't found one yet, not even here...
Can someone enlighten me?

This is the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

    List<DrawerItem> dataList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing
        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Add Drawer Item to dataList



        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Message", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Likes", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Games", R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Lables", R.drawable.ic_action_labels));


        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Search", R.drawable.ic_action_search));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Cloud", R.drawable.ic_action_cloud));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Camara", R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Video", R.drawable.ic_action_video));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Groups", R.drawable.ic_action_group));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Import & Export",
                R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));


        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            SelectItem(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void SelectItem(int possition) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (possition) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new FragmentThree();
                args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new FragmentThree();
                args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 6:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 7:
                fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 8:
                fragment = new FragmentThree();
                args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 9:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 10:
                fragment = new FragmentTwo();
                args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 11:
                fragment = new FragmentThree();
                args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            case 12:
                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getItemName());
                args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                        .getImgResID());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
        setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            SelectItem(position);

        }
    }

}
```

CustomDrawerAdapter.java:

```
 public class CustomDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> {

    Context context;
    List<DrawerItem> drawerItemList;
    int layoutResID;

    public CustomDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
                               List<DrawerItem> listItems) {
        super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
        this.context = context;
        this.drawerItemList = listItems;
        this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
            drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);
            drawerHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);

            view.setTag(drawerHolder);

        } else {
            drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();

        }

        DrawerItem dItem = (DrawerItem) this.drawerItemList.get(position);

        drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(
                dItem.getImgResID()));
        drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getItemName());

        return view;
    }

    private static class DrawerItemHolder {
        TextView ItemName;
        ImageView icon;
    }
}
```

DrawerItem.java:

```
public class DrawerItem {

    String ItemName;
    int imgResID;

    public DrawerItem(String itemName, int imgResID) {
        super();
        ItemName = itemName;
        this.imgResID = imgResID;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return ItemName;

    }
        public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        ItemName = itemName;
    }
    public int getImgResID() {
        return imgResID;
    }
    public void setImgResID(int imgResID) {
        this.imgResID = imgResID;
    }

}
```

Comment: In other words you want your ListView to have some items with a different layout?

Comment: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UC1gAayQdak/Ug_I8QdbP_I/AAAAAAAAAsI/fzmtJ-kAhXo/s1600/sectionlist.png  This is what I want. See those titles: **My friends** and **AndroidVersion** ?

Comment: I see. Post your adapter code.

Comment: I posted the CustomDrawerAdapter.java

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to create 2 different layout files for your normal items, and for the header items. For example:

**list_header.xml:**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then make your adapter needs to override a few methods so it recognizes 2 different types and uses different `convertViews` for them:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (getItem(position).getImgResID() == 0) {
        // Header type = 1
        return 1;
    } else {
        // Normal item types = 0
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Finally all the magic happens inside of the `getView` method. Let it check if item at specific position is a header, and inflate a specific layout:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;

    DrawerItem dItem = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();
        if (dItem.getImgResID() == 0) {
            // Inflate header layout
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, parent, false);
            drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            // ...
        } else {
            // Inflate normal layout
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            drawerHolder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
        convertView.setTag(drawerHolder);
    } else {
        drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    drawerHolder.ItemName = dItem.getItemName();

    // ...

    return convertView;
}
```

Then your items would look like this:

```
DrawerItem("Header1", 0, true);
DrawerItem("Message", R.drawable.ic_action_email);
DrawerItem("Message", R.drawable.ic_action_email);
DrawerItem("Header2", 0, true);
DrawerItem("Message", R.drawable.ic_action_email);
```

Note: header is a simple item without a drawable (img res id == 0).

Comment: Last line **drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) convertView.getTag();** gives me a warning: **Incompatible types**

Comment: @MasterZYuri Make sure you implement this to suit your project. This code is mostly snippets.

Comment: Ok, right now i'm getting only crashes.I have to go to sleep now, I'll try again tomorrow and let you know if it works.

Comment: Not working... I think the solution is on the website from where I made the app http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/  scroll down till you find **Customizing the Navigation Drawer**, there he adds the headers and a spinner, and here's the thing: he mixed the headers code with the spinner's code. Maybe you'll find a way to extract only the headers code.

Comment: Had any luck on that?

Comment: @MasterZYuri I know these snippets work if you implement them right. I'm sorry but I won't go on writing all the code for you, it would beat the purpose of this website.

Comment: I totally agree with that. Just 1 more thing, the **public int getViewTypeCount() {...** goes in the CustomDrawerAdapter.java right? along with the code below it.

Comment: Can't get it working... I thought that it's easy to add a simple header but it seems to be beyond me.